# Как вывести результат python функции в html шаблон Django?

Tags: python, django

```
def usd(request):
    DOLLAR_RUB = 'https://www.google.com/search?channel=trow5&client=firefox-b-d&q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BA+%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E+++'
    header = {'MY_USER_AGENT'}
    full_page = requests.get(DOLLAR_RUB, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
    convert = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'DFlfde', 'class': 'SwHCTb', 'data-precision': 2})
    convert = convert[0].tex
    
    return = convert
```

Как вывести результат функции выше, и вставить его в шаблон ?

```
<p class="curse">{{ ??? }}</p>
```

Comment: Например написав свой тэг https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать функцию render() и передать 3 аргументом словарь
где значением будет ваша переменная соnvert, а шаблоне получить
эту переменную можно по ключу {{ convert }}:

```
def usd(request):
  
  # ваш код

  template = 'app_name/your_page.html'
  return render(request,template,{'convert':convert})

<p class="curse">{{ convert }}</p>
```